# Existential unforgabilty of a separately signed message

Tags: signature

Assuming I have a valid signature scheme, and modify it like:

m = m0 || m1, and output Sign(sk, m0) || Sign(sk, m1).

While it is correct, would this violate existential unforgability?

Comment: This looks like an assignment. Hint: order.

Comment: You mean the order of the messages and subsequent ciphertexts are maintained?

If the encryption scheme isn't deterministic, how would that matter since it should be indistinguishable anyway?

Comment: What encryption would that be? I don't see any encryption.